# How to remove day grouping header for today's date in Agenda View?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I have following custom agenda command definition. What I would like to achieve is to group all tasks for today without wrapping them in the current date header.

```
  (setq org-agenda-custom-commands
        '(("o" "Custom Agenda"
           ((agenda "" ((org-agenda-overriding-header "\n  ⚡ Do Today ⚡\n⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺")
                    (org-agenda-remove-tags t)
                    (tags-todo "today")
                    (category-todo "today")
                    (org-agenda-highlight-todo)
                    (org-agenda-span 'day)
                    (org-agenda-skip-deadline-if-done)
                    (org-agenda-time-grid nil)
                    (org-agenda-prefix-format "  %-3i  %10b %15t%10s")))))))))))))
```

**TL:DR** How to remove current day header, but still group the tasks by today's date?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define `org-agenda-format-date` either as a string or as a function to format the date in the agenda. `C-h v org-agenda-format-date RET` says:

> Format string for displaying dates in the agenda.
>
> Used by the daily/weekly agenda.  This should be a format string
> understood by ‘format-time-string’, or a function returning the
> formatted date as a string.  The function must take a single
> argument, a calendar-style date list like (month day year).

So all you need to do is add a setting for it in your org-agenda-custom-commands:

```el
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
        '(("o" "Custom Agenda"
           ((agenda "" ((org-agenda-overriding-header "\n  ⚡ Do Today ⚡\n⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺")
                    (org-agenda-remove-tags t)
                    (tags-todo "today")
                    (category-todo "today")
                    (org-agenda-highlight-todo)
                    (org-agenda-span 'day)
                    (org-agenda-skip-deadline-if-done)
                    (org-agenda-time-grid nil)
                    (org-agenda-format-date "")  ; <---- HERE
                    (org-agenda-prefix-format "  %-3i  %10b %15t%10s")))))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much!